# php issue in passing an array to Paypal

Tags: php

I have an array of variables that I passing to Paypal via . The problem I have is when the Paypal screen loads the items, qty, price section is empty. Here is the code snippet for the passing:- (arrays cart_stock and cart_price hold the data to pass, $tmp_cart_count hold the total number of items to pass)

```
<?php 
echo "<form target='PayPal' action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>";
echo "<input name='cmd' value='_xclick' type='hidden' />";
echo "<input name='upload' value='1' type='hidden' />";
echo "<input name='business' value='sales@danskvintage.com.au' type='hidden' />";

// other irrelevant variables are passed here //

$i=0;$count=1;
while ($i < $tmp_cart_count)
    {
    echo "<input name='custom' value='".$_SESSION['cart_stock'][$i]."' type='hidden' >";
    echo "<input name='item_name_".($count)."' value='".$_SESSION['cart_title'][$i]."' type='hidden' >";
    echo "<input name='quantity_".($count)."' value='1' type='hidden' >";            
    echo "<input name='amount_".($count)."' value='".$_SESSION['cart_price'][$i]."' type='hidden' >";
    echo "<input name='shipping_".($count)."' value='0' type='hidden' >";
    $i++;
    $count++;
    }
echo "<input type='submit' value='PayPal'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as it has me stumped.

Comment: Does `$_SESSION['cart_price'][$i]` contain anything?

Comment: try to modify `action` attribute of `<form>` tag to send data to some script at your server. In this script dump all post data like `var_dump($_POST);` to see if correct data is sent through form.

Comment: The variables are live. a print_r of the array shows it is populated. I also have the following code inside the while loop.// //err chk
echo "item_name_".($count)." is: ".$_SESSION['cart_title'][$i]."</br>";
echo "quantity_".($count)." is: 1</br>";
echo "amount_".($count)." is: ".$_SESSION['cart_price'][$i]."</br>";

Comment: the var_dump($_POST) came back ok, the vars were populated. Its got me baffled.

Comment: @webbandit All the vars are populated. I echo'd them before passing and they came up ok. I also redirected the form to a local file and var_dump'd the POST, all are populated correctly.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this Paypal system but you should make sure that your sent data format is similar to format shown in Paypal API docs.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
echo "<input name='cmd' value='_xclick' type='hidden' />";
```

into

```
echo "<input name='cmd' value='_cart' type='hidden' />";
```

I believe that might help.